# How can we create an exe in visual studio 2012 express?

Tags: vb.net

i want to create .exe  in visual studio 2012 express.But the setup and deployment projects option is not exist there in vs 2012 express that i used.kindly give me a solution for this problem.how can we create .exe ?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile and run your project Visual Studio creates an executable file for your project under `debug` directory in your project directory.

Comment: Or in `Release` folder it it is compiling in release mode... or in any other folder if explicitly specified on the project settings.